# NoFileAssignedException exception when generating karaf feature with maven

Tags: maven, apache-karaf

I have an error in my karaf feature project wher I run my mvn install. Here is the pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>com.dmasoft.karaf.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>assemblies-parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<groupId>com.dmasoft.karaf.example.feature</groupId>
<artifactId>dmasoft-feature</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>feature</packaging>
<name>${project.groupId}/${project.artifactId}:${project.packaging}:${project.version}</name>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.karaf.tooling</groupId>
            <artifactId>karaf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

When I run my mvn clean install I get this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:3.0.0-M1:install (default-install) on project dmasoft-feature: NoFileAssignedException: The packaging plugin for this project did not assign a main file to the project but it has attachments. Change packaging to 'pom'. -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: The issue is simply that the karaf plugin does not correctly define the main artifact  see detailed descriptions https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MINSTALL-151 Apart from that it shows that you have not pinned all plugins versions in your build which is by definition bad practice.

Comment: Thanks!! the problem was the incompatibility between the maven install plugin and the karaf plugin. As it's said in the link you posted, the solution is to change the maven install plugin to the previous version.

Comment: This is not really the solution only temporarily. Cause the issue is in karaf-maven-plugin...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The maven-install-plugin:3.0.0-M1 was released as of 01/10/2018
Since, I got the same error with flexmojos projects where packaging was set to .

Solution is to set the version for the maven-install-plugin to the previous version (2.5.2) explicitly so it won't resolve the version automatically.
Note: I had to do this for the maven-deploy-plugin too. There may be others.

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: This is a workaround. What is the real solution?

Comment: This doesn't solve the underlying problem and isn't useful unless you want to stay on this exact same version of Maven forever.

Answer (score 0):

Now you can change mule.tools.version to 1.7 1.7 instead of setting maven plugins version if you are using it.